# Is it possible to have a list of files transferred after a successful transfer in WMQ-FTE?

Tags: ibm-mq, file-transfer, websphere-mq-fte

I would like to move some files to a time-stamped directory after I transfer them using WMQ-FTE. I am running v7.0.4.1.

My problem is that there are always new files being written to the directory I am transferring out of, so just blindly transferring everything is not the way. I also batch up the transfer triggers as they happen in batches of about 1000, so only one transfer occurs per 1000 files to be transferred.

I was hoping there would be some metadata that contained a list of the paths of the files transferred so I could move them to a directory before or after the transfer happens. The directory creation would be part of a pre or post source call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [`DestinationTransferEndExit.java` API documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/destination_transfer_end_exit.htm).  In particular, look at the `fileResults` parameter.  An ANT task can use this parameter to perform actions on specific files.

```
/**
 * Invoked immediately after the completion of a transfer on the agent acting as
 * the destination of the transfer.
 * 
 * @param transferExitResult
 *            a result object reflecting whether or not the transfer completed
 *            successfully.
 * 
 * @param sourceAgentName
 *            the name of the agent acting as the source of the transfer.
 * 
 * @param destinationAgentName
 *            the name of the agent acting as the destination of the
 *            transfer.  This is the name of the agent that the 
 *            implementation of this method will be invoked from.
 * 
 * @param environmentMetaData
 *            meta data about the environment in which the implementation
 *            of this method is running.  This information can only be read,
 *            it cannot be updated by the implementation.  The constants
 *            defined in <code>EnvironmentMetaDataConstants</code> class can 
 *            be used to access the data held by this map.
 * 
 * @param transferMetaData
 *            meta data to associate with the transfer.  The information can
 *            only be read, it cannot be updated by the implementation.  This 
 *            map may also contain keys with IBM reserved names.  These 
 *            entries are defined in the <code>TransferMetaDataConstants</code> 
 *            class and have special semantics.
 * 
 * @param fileResults
 *            a list of file transfer result objects that describe the source
 *            file name, destination file name and result of each file transfer
 *            operation attempted.
 * 
 * @return    an optional description to enter into the log message describing
 *            transfer completion.  A value of <code>null</code> can be used
 *            when no description is required.
 */
String onDestinationTransferEnd(TransferExitResult transferExitResult,
                String sourceAgentName,
                String destinationAgentName,
                Map<String, String>environmentMetaData,
                Map<String, String>transferMetaData, 
                List<FileTransferResult>fileResults);
```

Comment: I didn't specify that all this has to happen on the source server, but I found the exit for source transfers, SourceTransferEndExit.java. I will implement and report my findings